# Using 386SWAT to trace a program through a transition from real mode into protected mode

Tags: ms-dos, debugging

The 386SWAT debugger seems to be able to continue tracing a real-mode (not V86) program that goes into protected mode, but I don't quite understand how to configure 386SWAT, and I can't find any example in assembly language.
Please does anyone know how to do this ?
Or know of another debugger that knows how to change mode (RM -> PM) while tracing ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything in the [documentation](http://www.sudleyplace.com/swat/swatdoc.html) about this? The author's email address is on that page so it would be worth making contact. I noticed on looking at the files that there are a couple of example ASM applications in the DPMITSR.ZIP and EPM.ZIP files supplied with the application.

Comment: I have contacted Mr Bob Smith twice for 386 SWAT, but he says he has long since abandoned this software.I think that at the end of development, this program was much more oriented to be used with Windows or a DPMI or VCPI server.

Comment: So perhaps the int 67h intended to inform 386SWAT that the program is entering PM mode (and therefore that the segment registers become selectors), do not work because they may not have been tested for this way starting from the RM. Because even Ctrl-Alt-Pad5 didn't work in real mode, unless RMLIDT option is present in 386SWAT.PRO, so I wonder if 386SWAT is really functional or not to continue tracing from real mode to protected mode. That's why I'm trying to know if anyone has already managed to do it, because INT 67h DEF0, DEF2 and DEF3 are accepted but INT3 does not break in protected mode.

Comment: [This forum](https://www.bttr-software.de/forum/board.php) seems to have a few 386SWAT posts so I would suggest posting a question there.